# Trying to make my VM inside a VPS connect with external network (Virtualbox)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vps

so i bought a VPS (Ubuntu) and installed a windows VM (Virtualbox) inside of it, but i want to make it interact with external networks, running a command to see the adapters on the VPS gives me this:

```
network        Virtio network device
eth0    network        Ethernet interface
```

I'm wondering if i could use the bridged mode (I've tried all modes available on bridge mode, but when the VM was turned ON, it showed it had no connection), or if there's other way to make it interact with the real world.

Comment: "I've tried using it, to no avail" The purpose of a question is not that you just mention that you did anything and were not happy with the results. Instead you are supposed to describe what exactly you did and what exactly happened. Otherwise we could just "answer" with "Yes, you can use bridge mode".

Comment: I've tried all modes available on bridge mode, but when the VM was turned ON, it showed it had no connection

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.